# Paid snaps for Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

Can you publish a paid snap for Ubuntu Desktop or is this feature still not available in the Ubuntu Store?

I cannot see any option in 
https://dashboard.snapcraft.io/dev/snaps/
Maybe I am using the wrong site, but it has been a promised feature for at least 2 years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infrastructure for publishing paid snaps in place. We're not quite ready to launch yet. We wouldn't want to launch a service for paid snaps without all the necessary testing and support infrastructure in place. It's coming though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer....any estimate?

Comment: Not currently, no. Sorry.

Comment: One year have passed...more than one year. Any news? Thanks.

Comment: Not currently, no. Sorry.

Comment: Any news? It seems like it's been a while. Is it still being worked on, or is it going to be scrapped? Because I think having a real app store is necessary for getting more mainstream apps, which would then help Linux gain traction (along with PCs being sold in mainstream retail outlets and doing actual marketing to the general public)